# How to specify kbd modifiers with SendInput()?

Tags: c, winapi, keyboard-events

I'm using the Windows API SendInput() call to simulate keyboard events.  The following snippet (irrelevant details omitted) works perfectly for sending a sequence of characters:

```
wchar_t txt = ...;
INPUT *input = ...;
size_t nInput = 0;

for (unsigned int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = 0;
    input[nInput].ki.wScan = txt[j];
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    nInput++;
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = 0;
    input[nInput].ki.wScan = txt[j];
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    nInput++;
}
SendInput(nInput, input, sizeoF(INPUT));
```

Now I'm trying to send single keypresses, with modifiers. I tried the following code:

```
bool control, alt shift;
wchar_t chr;

if (control) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    nInput++;
}
if (alt) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    nInput++;
}
if (shift) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    nInput++;
}

input[nInput].ki.wVk = 0;
input[nInput].ki.wScan = chr;
input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
nInput++;
input[nInput].ki.wVk = 0;
input[nInput].ki.wScan = chr;
input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
nInput++;

if (shift) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    nInput++;
}
if (alt) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    nInput++;
}
if (control) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    nInput++;
}
SendInput(nInput, input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

However, modifiers don't seem to get through, i.e., even though, say `control` is set to true, the event sequence is received as a plain keypress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661817/how-to-specify-kbd-modifiers-with-sendinput/661919#661919) did not work out, but it lead me to the correct solution. In short: do not use `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` for individual keypresses, rather, convert the character to a virtual key code, and send it that way.  Here's the relevant code:

```
SHORT virtKey = VkKeyScan((TCHAR) chr);
input[nInput].ki.wVk = LOBYTE(virtKey);
input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = 0;
nInput++;
input[nInput].ki.wVk = LOBYTE(virtKey);
input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
nInput++;
```

I have not tested how this works for non-ASCII unicode characters, that are mapped to non-English keyboard layouts, and what happens when the layout set for my app is different from the layout set for the application in the front.

Comment: @David, you should probably accept this answer otherwise SO will continue to bother you with "have you thought of accepting an answer to this question".

Comment: @Pax: sure, I'll do that, but first I wanted to give others a chance to improve my answer or to point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The only piece of code I've found which may indicate your problem sets the scan code in the `ki` structure as well.

Try changing your modifier sections to be:

```
if (control) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input[nInput].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0); 
    nInput++;
}
if (alt) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input[nInput].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU, 0); 
    nInput++;
}
if (shift) {
    input[nInput].ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;
    input[nInput].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input[nInput].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT, 0); 
    nInput++;
}
```

and see if that helps.

If that still doesn't work, try setting the `dwFlags` to `KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE` instead of `0` (only for the modifier keys).

Also do it for the key-up events as well and I'm assuming that you're setting `input[nInput].type` to `INPUT_KEYBOARD`, yes? Your code doesn't indicate this.

For reference, it was found on [this page](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.ui/2004-03/0053.html).

Comment: "you're setting input[nInput].type to INPUT_KEYBOARD" - yes, of course.

Comment: Not "of course", I never assume anything that's not plainly stated (and sometimes I even doubt those :-). Anyhow, did you try the scan codes?

Comment: Fair enough :-) Anyway, the scan codes did not help, but the page you referenced lead me to the solution. I'll post it as an answer. +1, and thanks!

Comment: No probs, glad I could help, if only a little. I'm off to bed, it's late here in Oz.